# Printing data in Excel ver 14.0 in a maxed cell

Tags: printing, microsoft-excel-2010, cells

I have set the cell to the maximum size (column width of 255 and row height of 409.5).  In order to view all of the data in the cell, I have to use up/down arrows. I don't need to necessarily view all of the data in the cell at one time, however I do need it to print, and it's only printing what's viewable (not what you can scroll through).....any suggestions on how to get the entire cell to print?

Thanks!

Comment: Excel is a horrible word processor. Is it possible to copy and paste the text into Notepad or Word in order to print?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Cell
2. On the Page Layout tab, in the Page Setup group, click Print Area, and then click Set Print Area
3. Confirm single cell selection (*as pic*)
4. File and Print

[image: Confirm single page layout]